# Macro to simplify recursive function syntax

Tags: scheme, racket

As I learn scheme and racket I find myself repeating this pattern again and again. Where I have a recursive function where some of the parameters to the function change but some of the parameters do not. I build an outer function that takes all the parameters and within that define an inner function that takes only the changing parameters and recur on that.

As a concrete example heres a case based somewhat on a function exercise in "The Little Schemer"

```
;inserts an item to the right of an element in a list   
(define   (insert-to-right new old lat)    
  (define (insert-to-right lat)  
    (cond  
      [(null? lat) lat]  
      [(eq? old (car lat) ) (cons old (cons new (cdr lat)))]  
      [else (cons (car lat) (insert-to-right    (cdr lat)))]))  
    (insert-to-right lat))
```

Is it possible to build a macro define* and an operator (for example a vertical bar) such that I would type:

```
(define*   (insert-to-right new old | lat)      
    (cond  
      [(null? lat) lat]  
      [(eq? old (car lat) ) (cons old (cons new (cdr lat)))]  
      [else (cons (car lat) (insert-to-right    (cdr lat)))]))
```

and this would then expand into the first form with all the parameters being passed to the outer function but only the parameters after the vertical  bar being passed to the inner loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing around I've built a macro that does what I want.

```
(define-syntax-rule 
  (define* (function-name (outer-var ...)  (inner-var ...)) expr ...)
  (define (function-name outer-var ... inner-var ...) 
    (define (function-name inner-var ...)expr ...)
    (function-name inner-var ...)))   


(define*   (insert-to-right [new old] [lat])        
    (cond  
      [(null? lat) lat]  
      [(eq? old (car lat) ) (cons old (cons new (cdr lat)))]  
      [else (cons (car lat) (insert-to-right    (cdr lat)))])) 

> (insert-to-right 11 3 '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
'(1 2 3 11 4 5 6)
```

In the define* statement it doesn't use a separator between the inner and outer parameters (as I originally tried to do) but puts the inner and outer parameters in the define* statement into separate lists which I think is more idiomatic Scheme/Racket.

Answer (score 8):

You could write such a macro, but you could also just use named let:

```
(define (insert-to-right new old lat)
  (let loop ([lat lat])
    (cond
      [(null? lat)         lat]  
      [(eq? old (car lat)) (cons old (cons new (cdr lat)))]  
      [else                (cons (car lat) (loop (cdr lat)))])))
```

Comment: Thanks Matthias.  I'm wondering how I can do it without either an inner function or a named let.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use macros to do this.  This is a textbook case for higher-order functions; in particular, I believe your example can be written with [`pair-fold-right` from SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#pair-fold-right).  Untested code (I hope this is right):

```
(define (insert-to-right new old lat)
  (pair-fold-right (lambda (pair rest)
                     (if (eq? (car pair) old)
                         (cons (car pair)
                               (cons new rest))
                         pair))
                   '()
                   lat))

;;; Example implementation of pair-fold-right, just for one list—your Scheme system
;;; probably has this as a library function somewhere
(define (pair-fold-right fn init list)
  (if (null? list)
      init
      (fn list (pair-fold-right fn init (cdr list)))))
```

Comment: Thanks Sacundim, but I was only using insert-to-right as an example.  The question was about simplifying the syntax of the general case where I am recurring on a function where some of the parameters are invariant and some are not.

Comment: Well, my advice there is just don't do it.  Macros make code harder to read and troubleshoot, and there really are just a few things that absolutely require them.  For example, (a) adding expression forms that don't evaluate all of their subexpressions, or (b) adding new types of binding forms (expressions that bind new variables).

Comment: What about any form with side effects such as: 
    (define-syntax-rule (increment! X) (set! X (add1 X)))

Which lets you make this classic  more clear:

(define (make-counter)
       (define counter 0)
      (lambda () (increment! counter)  counter))

    (define counter1 (make-counter))